# I'm getting blurred squares instead of sharp ones as an output

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

I have the code like this:
[THIS](https://pastebin.com/dpMrYNyu)

and I'm getting blurred squares instead of sharp ones after saving the image of `training_data`.

I'm unable to spot the error after having been trying for the whole day :-(

I wish to save the output images of Jupyter Notebook in the sharp way as is the second image attached:

[1st IMAGE bulurred and incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYhsg.png)

[2nd Image sharp and correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp9s6.png)

I was manipulating with this line

import cv2
cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/Desktop/Untitled3.png", image_training)

and many other but I have failed.

**EDIT** I just want to save an image as generated into Jupyetr Notebook.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then click [edit] and update your question to ensure it is a [mcve]. Pictures of code are impossible to search, edit or run! *"Minimal"* means readers don't have to wade through pages of `matplotlib` stuff if irrelevant, nor install `tensorflow`  or `tqdm`.

Comment: Not following. Where are the images in your screenshots displaying that you are showing us? You are making separate files **so you need to open them in an image renderer to actually see what they are**, not necessarily take the default that the jupyter output tries to make. For example, I can clearly see that is all you did with the second one you shared. I cannot tell the context at all for the one just above that. And as Mark says, from your complex code, there is no way to easily parse what is making those two images different or even if your code matches. Give the file names like #1 & #2.